# Get the match with the string using substring javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Want to know if the substring of string is in the another string.

For eg..

`var firstString= test123;
var secondString= nest145;
var thirdString= test456;
var fourString= teating456;`

Result should be after comparing firstString and secondString

`est1` is matched.

Result should be after comparing firstString and thirdString

`test` is matched.

Result should be after comparing firstString and fourString

`No match found.`

Limit to check the word-length can be decided.For the above example it is 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple sample, where the matched letters needs to be next after each other.

```js
var firstString = 'test123';
var secondString = 'nest145';
var thirdString = 'test456';
var fourString = 'teating456';

function findMatchedChars(str1, str2, limit) {
  var result = '', s1 = str1, s2 = str2;
  if (str2.length > str1.length) {
    s1 = str2;
    s2 = str1;
  }
  for (var x = 0; x < s1.length; x++) {
    if (s1[x] == s2[x]) {
      result += s1[x];
    } else {
      if (result.length > 0 && result.length >= limit) return result;
      result = '';
    }
  }
  if (result.length > 0 && result.length >= limit) return result;
  return 'No matches';  
}

alert(findMatchedChars(firstString,secondString,4));
alert(findMatchedChars(firstString,thirdString,4));
alert(findMatchedChars(firstString,fourString,4));
```

Comment: @Vaibs_Cool You're welcome, I also made an update to make it more solid.

Answer (score 0):

This is LCS problem with tow string...
[LCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem#Solution_for_two_sequences)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the regex version:

```js
var firstString = 'test123';
var secondString = 'nest145';
var thirdString = 'test456';
var fourString = 'teating456';

function findDups(str1, str2, limit) {
  var re = '.*([^\\s]{' + limit + '}).*\\s+.*\\1.*'
  var m = (str1 + " " + str2).match(re)
  if (m != null) {
    alert(m[1])
  } else
    alert('No matches')
}

findDups(firstString, secondString, 4)
findDups(firstString, thirdString, 4)
findDups(firstString, fourString, 4)
```